# How do I create an Azure Service Bus subscription filter using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, azureservicebus

I am able to list the filters for a specified topic subscription.  And for each filter to see the rules.
Snippet:

`from azure.servicebus.management import ServiceBusAdministrationClient, CorrelationRuleFilter servicebus_mgmt_client = ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) for rule_properties in servicebus_mgmt_client.list_rules(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME): print(rule_properties)`

This returns something like:
{'name': 'customer', 'filter': <azure.servicebus.management._models.CorrelationRuleFilter object at 0x104877760>, 'action': None, 'created_at_utc': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 17, 12, 59, 8, 164754, tzinfo=<isodate.tzinfo.Utc object at 0x1047d2b80>)}

Questions:
1- How do I see the specifics of the filter?  I want to know its type ("CorrelationFilter"), and its Custom Properties (key/value).

2- How do I create a rule? Something like:

`servicebus_mgmt_client.create_rule(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, myfilter)`

But what should be the syntax of myfilter?  I suspect it has something to with the CorrelationRuleFilter.

Nothing in the Microsoft GitHub ServiceBusAdministrationClient documentation about creating or deleting filters in a subscription.
Various Google answers, either in .NET or outdated.

Otherwise, reading messages, listing subscriptions, checking the DLQ, all works.

Comment: with the code below  a Rule 'new-rule' with filter 'CorrelationRuleFilter' [created](https://i.imgur.com/jFirlmc.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample code below able to create a Rule 'new-rule' with filter 'CorrelationRuleFilter' created.

```py
from azure.servicebus.management import (
    ServiceBusAdministrationClient,
    CorrelationRuleFilter,
)

CONNECTION_STR = "Endpoint=sb://hedwig-servicebus-prod.servicebus.windows.net/;"
TOPIC_NAME = "rules-output"
SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "notificationengine-ts"


def view_filter_details(filter):
    print(f"Filter Type: {type(filter).__name__}")
    if isinstance(filter, CorrelationRuleFilter):
        print("Custom Properties:")
        for key, value in filter.properties.items():
            print(f"{key}: {value}")


def main():
    servicebus_mgmt_client = ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR
    )
    for rule_properties in servicebus_mgmt_client.list_rules(
        TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
    ):
        print(f"Rule Name: {rule_properties['name']}")
        view_filter_details(rule_properties["filter"])

    new_filter = CorrelationRuleFilter(correlation_id="my-correlation-id")
    new_rule_name = "new-rule"
    servicebus_mgmt_client.create_rule(
        TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, new_rule_name, filter=new_filter
    )
    print(f"Rule '{new_rule_name}' with filter '{type(new_filter).__name__}' created.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm.  I would add for others that Custom Properties may be added as follows:  
new_filter = CorrelationRuleFilter(correlation_id="20230815",label="20230815",properties={"customer_shortname":"ACME"})